# Angular JS multiple filter query

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm a newcomer to Angular/JS so please be kind ...
I'm having a problem (probably with myself trying to wrap my brain around Angular) with some code where I want to use two different filters (I think) on a dataset with ng-repeat. Firstly here is a screen shot of the html form items and data output I am working with;

[image: Webpage]

Here is the basic (stripped down) HTML code for the setup above;

```
<div ng-controller="customersCrtl">

      Records Per Page:
      <select ng-model="entryLimit" class="form-control">
        <option>50</option>
        <option>100</option>
        <option>250</option>
        <option>500</option>
        <option>1000</option>
      </select>

      Record Type:
      <select ng-model="entryType" class="form-control">
        <option>All</option>
        <option>Baptism</option>
        <option>Marriage</option>
        <option>Burial</option>
      </select>

      Filter Text:
      <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" placeholder="Filter" class="form-control" />

      Filtered {{ filtered.length }} of {{ totalItems }} Total Records

      <div ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th>Event Date <a ng-click="sort_by('eventDate');">sort</a></th>
            <th>Event Type <a ng-click="sort_by('type');">sort</a></th>
            <th>Indivdual(s) <a ng-click="sort_by('name');">sort</a></th>
            <th>Location <a ng-click="sort_by('location');">sort</a></th>
            <th></th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
              <td>{{data.eventDate | date:'mediumDate'}}</td>
              <td>{{data.type}}</td>
              <td>{{data.name}}</td>
              <td><a href="#">{{data.location}}</a></td>
              <td><a href="#">View Record</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

... and here is the associated Angular JS code I currently have;

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('ajax/getMarkers.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 50; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.entryType = 'All'; //Record type to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

getMarkers.php in the above Angular code snippet returns JSON results formatted like so;

```
{"id":"646","eventDate":"1576-05-13","name":"John Phillip","type":"Baptism","churchName":"St. Marys","locationid":"563","location":"Swainswick, Somerset, UK","lat":"51.414211","lng":"-2.351418"},
{"id":"647","eventDate":"1577-07-01","name":"Jane Volantyne","type":"Baptism","churchName":"St. Mary the Virgin","locationid":"564","location":"Horsham, Sussex, UK","lat":"51.059750","lng":"-0.330879"},
{"id":"132","eventDate":"1634-05-09","name":"Katherine Stanley","type":"Burial","churchName":"St. James","locationid":"567","location":"Titsey, Surrey, UK","lat":"51.276505","lng":"0.018909"}
... etc. etc.
```

This currently works in so-far-as if a user types something in the "Filter Text" box, the table updates to only show entries that match the user text.

This is fine, but what I also want to be able to do is use the drop down "Record Type" box (with the defined entries All, Baptism, Burial, Marriage) to only show/filter the records with that particular "Event Type" in the table.
Is this even possible? Can you apply two concurrent filters to an ng-repeat in Angular, because I've tried and failed several times and am on the verge of giving up!!!

Am I asking something stupidly difficult or stupidly easy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its very possible to filter the table based on multiple conditions, You could add a filter function to the table as:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:filterEvents | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
     <td>{{data.eventDate | date:'mediumDate'}}</td>
     <td>{{data.type}}</td>
     <td>{{data.name}}</td>
     <td><a href="#">{{data.location}}</a></td>
     <td><a href="#">View Record</a></td>
</tr>
```

Basically, `$scope.filterEvents` is called every time the table is populated and you could filter out the required items using this in the controller:

```
$scope.filterEvents = function(item){
//Here item is the array element from the table
 which is automatically passed in the filter function.

 return item.type.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.entryType.toLowerCase()) != -1 || 
        item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search.toLowerCase()) != -1 
}
```

Where , `$scope.entryType` is the option selected in the dropdown and `$scope.search` is the keyword for searching.

Ps: You would need to remove the `ng-change=filter()` from search textbox and handle the return if `$scope.entryType = "All"`

Comment: thanks for the reply and I take on board what you've suggested, but making those changes ends up with no results being listed on first loading of the page ...

Comment: Do you see any error on console? Also, did you remove this: `ng-show="filteredItems > 0"`

Comment: $scope.search is undefined

Comment: Add $scope.search = ""; at starting of the controller